# texmaker doesn't support Chinese in mac

Tags: xetex, texmaker

I use texmaker in Mac. But the Chinese characters does not show normally.  Just like:
[image]

It seems that it needs xelatex, but there is no corresponding option in the texmaker in mac. I know there is the option in windows in ctex. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: You don't need `xelatex`, if you don't want to. See my response

Comment: Cmd + shift + 3 to take a screenshot on mac

Answer (score 1):

You have to include some packages that support Chinese in your LaTeX document. For example like `\usepackage{CJK}`. See [this Wikibook entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Chinese) for information.

If you need to make the whole document Chinese, then either `\usepackage{babel}`(if you are using LaTeX) or `\usepackage{polyglossia}` (if you are using XeLaTeX).

Comment: The screen shot seems to show the source editor rather than the typeset document so I think the comments above are not relevant. Out of curiosity does the Chinese show if you open the source file in TeXShop? If so there might be some settings in TeXmaker for what fonts are used for the Editor's display.

Comment: @herb-schulz I think it is possible to show Chinese in the source document. So some users may trick themselves by accidentally input a full width character rather than a half-width character like what we use. It ended up couldn't be compiled since full width characters are not used for commands.

Comment: I have used the package CJK. I think it should not be relevant with the package. The problem is the Chinese cannot show normally in the source code file. The file can be compiled to a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

*After some chat in the comments, I made another attempt.*

In your preference window, find the field that controls the fonts of your editor. Change it to any fonts that supports Chinese.

For example: I am using Tex Studio (A fork of Texmaker), I would need to change my fonts in the editor by means of the `Font Family:` field in the `Editor` tab.

Comment: thanks. Though, the font-family setting does not show normal neither. But it will be enough for me.

Comment: @neal what do you mean normal fonts?

Comment: please see the content below, I do not why I cannot @ u.

Comment: @neal Do you mean the image above (and the chinese characters below it)?